# Object mapping with org.modelmapper.modelmapper

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have 2 objects :

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Agent {
    public int userID;
    public String name;
    public boolean isVoiceRecorded;
    public boolean isScreenRecorded;
    public boolean isOnCall;
    public LocalDateTime startEventDateTime;
}
public class AgentLine {
    public int userID;
    public String name;
    public boolean isVoiceRecorded;
    public boolean isScreenRecorded;
    public boolean isOnCall;
    public String startEventDateTime;
}
```

I would like to map between AgentLine to Agent. I can't use the default mapping because of the Localdatetime conversion.
I have defined :

```
    @Bean
    ModelMapper getModelMapper() {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        Converter<AgentLine, Agent> orderConverter = new Converter<AgentLine, Agent>() {
            @Override
            public Agent convert(MappingContext<AgentLine, Agent> mappingContext) {
                AgentLine s = mappingContext.getSource();
                Agent d = mappingContext.getDestination();
/*                d.userID = s.userID;
                d.name = s.name;*/
                d.startEventDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s.startEventDateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
                return d;
            }
        };
        modelMapper.addConverter(orderConverter);
        return modelMapper;
    }
```

In order to use it:

```
AgentLine line;
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;
Agent agent = modelMapper.map(line, Agent.class);
```

It works , but I do not want to specify all Agent properties in the convert method, I would like to specify the startEventDateTime conversion and the rest of the properties would be mapped by default.

In addition I have tried to define :

```
PropertyMap<AgentLine, Agent> orderMap = new PropertyMap<AgentLine, Agent>() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    map().setName(source.name);
                }
            };
modelMapper.addMappings(orderMap);
```

but , in the mapping you can't handle the date conversion. 
If I define for the mapper PropertyMap and Converter  the PropertyMap is ignored.

I do not want to specify all Agent properties in the convert method, I would like to specify the startEventDateTime conversion and the rest of the properties would be mapped by default.

Comment: take a look at my answer.. it will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `Converter` for mapping complex objects. You should use `TypeMap` for such purposes. Use `Converter` for custom conversion (for your case `String` to `LocalDateTime`).

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();    
Converter<String, LocalDateTime> dateTimeConverter = ctx -> ctx.getSource() == null ? null : LocalDateTime.parse(ctx.getSource(), DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
modelMapper.typeMap(AgentLine.class, Agent.class)
        .addMappings(mapper -> mapper.using(dateTimeConverter).map(AgentLine::getStartEventDateTime, Agent::setStartEventDateTime));
```

Comment: By the way, fields should have `private` modificator instead of `public`. Also use `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations for `AgentLine` class.